# How do I reserve low memory (pre OS)?

Tags: boot, bios, bda

**Background:** I need to reserve an amount of memory below 0xA0000 prior to my operating system starts. To do this I change the [0040:0013](http://bioscentral.com/misc/bda.htm) (or 0x413) word which is the amount of low memory available in KiB.

However, Windows and other operating systems use [E820h/INT15h](http://www.uruk.org/orig-grub/mem64mb.html) to query the memory layout and some BIOS:es doesn't reflect 0x413 changes to the E820h/INT15h BIOS function. Therefore I also have to hook the E820h function if needed.

**Question:** Is there another (more reliable) way to reserve low memory prior to the OS? Or any other way of changing the E820h/INT15h results other than hooking INT15h (by poking EBDA perhaps?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, but if you are not doing a bootloader, you could para-virtualize the os. You could look at Xen hypervisor for it.

Comment: Nice idea, unfortunately Xen is not an option for me